# Linux mint 13: Error starting MATE

Tags: linux-mint, startup, desktop-environment, mate-desktop

My Linux Mint installation seemed to work fine an hour ago, then I switched into Windows 7 which is installed on the same machine. When I restarted back into Mint, I got the following errors and can't continue:

> Could not update ICEauthority file, problem with the configuration server.
>
> /usr/lib/mateconfig/mateconfig-sanity-check-2 exited with status 256.
>
> The panel encountered a problem loading OAFIDD:Mate_mintMenu (do you want to delete the file?)

And something about caja settings as well.

After I click OK on all those, and say no to deleting the file I can see the desktop, with no icons and the applications menu is not working. How do I fix this?

Comment: update: I reinstalled linux mint, everything was fine, I applied updates and restarded my computer, then the same errors as in OP showed up again. I really don't know what to say.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect what is happening is that hibernation is on by default. Hibernation expects the disk to be in exactly the same state during shutdown and startup. Since you boot Windows, the disk gets modified. (I believe this is how it works, but I'm not sure. It does explain your symptoms.)

The solution is to ensure that hibernation is not enabled in your Linux Mint installation. In the meantime, you can fix this by booting into rescue mode and reinstalling all the packages on your system. Select the "(recovery mode)" entry in your GRUB menu, then when you are given a recovery shell, type the following:

```
dpkg --get-selections > selections
dpkg --clear-selections
dpkg --set-selections < selections
apt-get --reinstall dselect-upgrade
apt-get install -f # for posterity
```